# Extracting same properites to style in WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

I'm stuck with extracting some properties to element's style in my Xaml file.
I have many repeated blocks like:

```
<controls:RoundableToggleRadioButton Style="{StaticResource RoundableToggleRadioButtonStyle}">
<StackPanel>
    <Image Width="32"
           Margin="2"
           Source="Images/inbox_upload.png" />
    <TextBlock Margin="2"
               Foreground="White"
               Text="Extract"
               TextAlignment="Center" />
</StackPanel>
```

So I want to extract the same properties for every button to style and be able to change image and text. Something like this:

```
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
<Setter.Value>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Width="32"
                   Margin="2" />
            <TextBlock Margin="2"
                       Foreground="White"
                       TextAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
```

```
<controls:RoundableToggleRadioButton Style="{StaticResource RoundableToggleRadioButtonStyle}">
<StackPanel>
    <Image Source="Images/inbox_upload.png" />
    <TextBlock Text="Extract"/>
</StackPanel>
```

So is it possible at all? Or there is some workarounds? 
Thanks for any help)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new class that inherits Button

```
public class ImageTextButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof (ImageSource), typeof (ImageTextButton), null);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof (string), typeof (ImageTextButton), null);

    public ImageTextButton()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ImageTextButton);
    }

    public ImageSource Icon
    {
        get { return (ImageSource) GetValue(IconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wpfApplication3="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type wpfApplication3:ImageTextButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type wpfApplication3:ImageTextButton}">
                    <StackPanel Height="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Icon}" Stretch="Fill"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <wpfApplication3:ImageTextButton Text="Submit" Icon="Hydrangeas.jpg"></wpfApplication3:ImageTextButton>
</Grid>
```

Instead of creating new Text property you can also use the Content property of Button.

Comment: It's harder than I expected)) But it solves my problem. Thank you for your time!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the **application resources** to do that if you have so many xaml files and have to apply same style everywhere.

Here's a bit of code for example (in `app.xaml`)

```
<Application.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ButtonStyling" >
     <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,2,1,2"/>
     <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
  </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

and then, for your buttons (for example):

```
<Button Height="50" Width="250" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyling}" Content="Button 1" />
<Button Height="50" Width="250" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyling}" Content="Button 2" />
```

Hope this will help you to find what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It seems to me it's best I can do. But I searched more elegant way to do this stuff. Any way thank you very much!!!

Comment: Its good you find a better solution. you might mark any answer as solution so that people can find it easy who finds your question similar to thier problem.